# Rearrange ListView cell

Tags: java, android

I am new in android app development. I want to rearrange the ListView cell with drag and drop like we do in swift TableView.
I have searched a lot but didn't get the clear vision about how it should be done.
please help.

Answer (score 1):

In Android this can be done using the [ViewDragHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/customview/widget/ViewDragHelper).

For tips on implementation lookup some guide or documentation such as here:
[Drag and Swipe with RecyclerView](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-6a6f0c422efd)